# SSRS Subscription Failure Error

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have started getting this error since a week now when I try to schedule a report or change a schedule of a report.

> An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due
>   to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database.(rsReportServerDatabaseError) Get Online Help For more
>   information about this error navigate to the report server on the
>   local server machine, or enable remote errors

We have SQL Server 2008 installed along with SSRS running on the server.

I have never seen this happening before for almost a year now but suddenly it appeared. Along with this, report subscription is also messed up and some report are not been emailed as they have a error like:

> ***Failure sending mail: An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk
>   condition within the database.Mail will not be resent.***

I am not sure what caused this but if anyone has any idea of what is going on it will be great. Thanks you for your help. Please reply soooon !!!

Comment: It is obvious but did you check ReportServer database is running correctly?

Comment: Also check the Error Logs for more details.

Comment: Do you have a set password for your data sources that may have changed? Check the data sources that the reports use to make sure they can connect.

Answer (score 1):

Check your error log for details

```
c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

Typically this happens when the user who owns the subscription (usually the one who set it up) is no longer a valid user or disabled etc. Try dropping & recreating the sub to isolate *bad user* case.

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution for that :

[image]

Step 1 : Go To start -> **SQL Server Configuration Manager**

Step 2 : Select SQL Server Services -> **Right click on SQL Server Report Services -> Click Restart**

[image]

Refresh your page see your Report will run.

[image]

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Table Subscriptions, and Trigger "Subscription_delete_Schedule" and make sure the tempdb called in that trigger matches your temp db name. That helped my same issue